# How to remove a pattern of table row elements from a table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If I have the following table, which I can't manually touch, but can apply javascript to...

```html
<table data="customTable">
  <tr>
    <td>item 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="10"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>item 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="10"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

...when the DOM loads fully, how can I remove **every** instance of `<tr><td height="10"></td></tr>` from the above table via jQuery **or** raw JavaScript?  I don't need that row at all and its causing design issues for me.  This is my first time trying to learn how to replace a full pattern of elements.
Hopefully, this is doable via JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick.

#### jQuery

```js
$('td[height="10"]').parent().remove();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/uzv3fn2e/1/

#### Vanilla JS

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('td[height="10"]')).forEach(td => td.parentNode.remove());
```

https://jsfiddle.net/t7y6aqc5/

Comment: you don't need `Array.from` if you check the object returned from querrySelectorAll there a forEach function

Comment: And you don't need to increase the cyclomatic complexity by adding guards ;o)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `:has()` selector to select `tr` that has `td` with specific attribute

```
$("tr:has(td[height='10'])").remove()
```

```js
$("tr:has(td[height='10'])").remove()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table data="customTable">
  <tr>
    <td>item 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="10"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>item 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="10"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

without using jquery javascript has also `remove()`

```js
document.querySelectorAll("td").forEach(el => el.getAttribute("height") === "10" && el.parentNode.remove())
```

```html
<table data="customTable">
  <tr>
    <td>item 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="10"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>item 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="10"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```